# Delphi 7: function crashes upon call in dll, works in exe

Tags: delphi, function, dll, crash, pascal

I have a problem with a Delphi 7 string-decoder function ("Decrypt") I found online. It takes a string and four numeric values between 1 and 120 to decode it. Putting the function within an executable and running it works great. However, I want to run this within a DLL. I'm using an extra function to receive the necessary values from the calling task and call the decrypt function from there. For some reason I can't put my finger on, the host app crashes every time the dll calls the decrypt-function. For the last few hours I have been trying everything I could come up with to get this to work, but without success. I'm new to Delphi and Pascal in general, so may be I just overlooked something obvious. Either way, I'm lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here's the windows error that pops up upon crash:

```
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_0a9e
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00000000
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1031
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Here's the code that I use:

```
library decrypt_test_dll;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Dialogs;

{$R *.res}

function callfunction(externalstring, value1, value2, value3, value4: PAnsiChar):integer; cdecl;
var
  convkey1, convkey2, convkey3, convkey4 : string;
  convstring, decodedstring : string;
  Decrypt : function(Text : string; Key1, Key2, Key3, Key4 : Integer) : string;
begin
  convkey1 := value1;
  convkey2 := value2;
  convkey3 := value3;
  convkey4 := value4;
  convstring := externalstring;
  decodedstring := Decrypt(externalstring, strtoint(convkey1), strtoint(convkey2), strtoint(convkey3), strtoint(convkey4));
  showmessage(decodedstring);
end;

function Decrypt(Text : string; Key1, Key2, Key3, Key4 : Integer) : string;
var
 BufS, Hexa1, Hexa2 : string;
  BufI, BufI2, Divzr, Sc, Sl, Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Res1, Res2, Res3, Res4 : Integer;
begin
  showmessage('within decryption function');
 Sl := Length(Text);
  Sc := 0;
  BufS := '';
  if (Key1 in [1 .. 120]) and (Key2 in [1 .. 120]) and (Key3 in [1 .. 120]) and (Key4 in [1 .. 120]) then
    begin
      Divzr := Key1 * Key4;
      BufI2 := Key3 * Key2;
      Divzr := Divzr - BufI2;
      if Divzr = 0 then
        begin
          Result := '';
          Exit;
        end;
    end
  else
    begin
      Result := '';
      Exit;
    end;
  repeat
    for BufI := 1 to 4 do
      begin
        Inc(Sc);
        Hexa1 := IntToHex(Ord(Text[Sc]), 2);
        Inc(Sc);
        Hexa2 := IntToHex(Ord(Text[Sc]), 2);
        if Hexa1 = 'FF' then
          begin
            Hexa1 := '00';
            Hexa2 := '00';
          end;
        if Hexa1 = 'FE' then Hexa1 := '00';
        if Hexa1 = 'FD' then
          begin
            Hexa1 := Hexa2;
            Hexa2 := '00';
          end;
        case BufI of
          1 : Res1 := StrToInt('$' + Hexa1 + Hexa2);
          2 : Res2 := StrToInt('$' + Hexa1 + Hexa2);
          3 : Res3 := StrToInt('$' + Hexa1 + Hexa2);
          4 : Res4 := StrToInt('$' + Hexa1 + Hexa2);
        end;
      end;
    BufI := Res1 * Key4;
    BufI2 := Res2 * Key3;
    Num1 := BufI - BufI2;
    Num1 := Num1 div Divzr;
    BufI := Res2 * Key1;
    BufI2 := Res1 * Key2;
    Num2 := BufI - BufI2;
    Num2 := Num2 div Divzr;
    BufI := Res3 * Key4;
    BufI2 := Res4 * Key3;
    Num3 := BufI - BufI2;
    Num3 := Num3 div Divzr;
    BufI := Res4 * Key1;
    BufI2 := Res3 * Key2;
    Num4 := BufI - BufI2;
    Num4 := Num4 div Divzr;
    BufS := BufS + Chr(Num1) + Chr(Num2) + Chr(Num3) + Chr(Num4);
    until Sc >= Sl;
    Result := BufS;
end;

exports
  Decrypt index 1,
  callfunction index 2;

begin
end.
```

Comment: Hi, Zerobinary99.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  It looks like you've got a good question, but it's buried somewhere in 3 pages of code.  Can you narrow things down a bit?  What do you mean "it crashes"?  Does it raise an exception?  What message does it give?  What line does the error come from?  You should be able to get that if you run under the debugger.

Comment: Hi Mason, thanks for your quick reply. To my shame I have to admit that I don't really know how to use the debugger. I set a break point and ran the dll, but I couldn't make much sense out of the resulting debug window. 

Using "showmessage" I was able to track the line that crashes the dll down to:

decodedstring := Decrypt(externalstring, strtoint(convkey1), strtoint(convkey2), strtoint(convkey3), strtoint(convkey4));

I was also able to check that the decrypt-function doesn't get past the begin-section since a "showmessage" right there isn't even executed any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is all wrong:

```
function callfunction(externalstring, value1, value2, value3, value4: PAnsiChar):integer; cdecl;
var
  convkey1, convkey2, convkey3, convkey4 : string;
  convstring, decodedstring : string;
  Decrypt : function(Text : string; Key1, Key2, Key3, Key4 : Integer) : string;
begin
  convkey1 := value1;
  convkey2 := value2;
  convkey3 := value3;
  convkey4 := value4;
  convstring := externalstring;
  decodedstring := Decrypt(externalstring, strtoint(convkey1), strtoint(convkey2), strtoint(convkey3), strtoint(convkey4));
  showmessage(decodedstring);
end;
```

The local variable `Decrypt` is never assigned to. So when you call `Decrypt`, anything can happen. You need to move `callfunction` to the bottom of the unit so that it appears after the real `Decrypt`. And you need to remove the function pointer variable.

```
function callfunction(externalstring, value1, value2, value3, value4: PAnsiChar):integer; cdecl;
var
  convkey1, convkey2, convkey3, convkey4 : string;
  convstring, decodedstring : string;
begin
  convkey1 := value1;
  convkey2 := value2;
  convkey3 := value3;
  convkey4 := value4;
  convstring := externalstring;
  decodedstring := Decrypt(externalstring, strtoint(convkey1), strtoint(convkey2), strtoint(convkey3), strtoint(convkey4));
  showmessage(decodedstring);
end;
```

You also should not use `string` as a parameter (or indeed a return value) in an exported DLL function. It's not a valid type for interop since it relies on both sides of the interface using the same `string` implementation, and the same memory manager. You need to find a different way to define the `Decrypt` interface, if you are going to export it. Or possibly you should not be exporting that function at all. Impossible for me to know with any certainty. My guess is that you are actually calling `callfunction` rather than `Decrypt` from the calling code. Anyway, in its current state, you must not export `Decrypt`.

One other point to make. When you ask a question that involves a module interface, you should always show both sides of the interface. Here you have shown the DLL, but not the code that calls into the DLL. The error could be there. Indeed, there could be an error there in addition to the errors I have pointed out.

Comment: Thanks a lot David! Moving the call-function below the decrypt-function and removing the function pointer variable did the trick. I was under the impression that the location of functions within the source wasn't important at all.

Comment: @Zerobinary99 Location of functions isn't really important. But you had to move it here because otherwise the compiler would not have known what to do with the `Decrypt` symbol since it had not been introduced. I have a hunch that you added that `Decrypt` local variable when you added the `callfunction` procedure. Is that right? What you needed to do was either what I suggested, or to use a forward declaration, or to split the code into units.

Comment: Your hunch was correct ;) I added the Decrypt variable after the compiler complained about not knowing it.

"My guess is that you are actually calling callfunction rather than Decrypt from the calling code. Anyway, in its current state, you must not export Decrypt."

Yes, I'm calling callfunction. Decrypt wasn't actually supposed to be exported. I was just distracted when I wrote the exports.

"You also should not use string as a parameter (or indeed a return value) in an exported DLL function."

Actually, the string is kept within the dll and processed by callfunction later on :)

Answer (score 0):

If the string manipulation code works as shown in an exe but not from a DLL check that the DLL has the delphi memory manager as the FIRST uses item.

```
uses
  ShareMem
```

This is implicitt in a Dephi exe, but not in its DLLs.

This is always a favorite problem with Delphi 6 DLLs and strings, cant say if its still applicable in Delphi 7 however!

Comment: Thank you for this hint. It indeed doesn't seem to be a problem in Delphi 7 any more, because the dll runs fine now even without adding ShareMem to uses. Still, upon creating an empty dll from the project wizard, the dll's header contains a comment also suggesting the use of ShareMem.

Comment: @Zerobinary99 No, this is still an issue in D7 and indeed in all Delphi versions. This is really the subject of the penultimate paragraph in my answer. But since you are not calling `Decrypt` from the executable program, you are not getting caught out. Your `callfunction` is fine because it uses `PAnsiChar` which is a legit interop type.